# Undefined subroutine called

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am trying to do simple module usage in Perl:

Flame/Text.pm:

```
package Flame::Text;
sub words { … }
1;
```

Flame/Query.pm:

```
package Flame::Query;
use Flame::Text qw(words);
sub parse_query { words(shift); }
parse_query 'hi';
1;
```

Why am I getting the following error message?

> Undefined subroutine `&Flame::Query::words` called at Flame/Query.pm line 3.

The following works just fine:

```
package Flame::Query;
use Flame::Text;
sub parse_query { Flame::Text::words(shift); }
parse_query 'hi';
1;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You never imported or exported the `words` subroutine from the `Flame::Text` package. A statement `use Some::Module @args` is equivalent to:

```
BEGIN {
  require Some::Module;
  Some::Module->import(@args);
}
```

that is, the `import` method is called with the specified arguments. This method would usually  export various symbols from one package into the calling package.

Don't write your own `import`, rather you can inherit one from the `Exporter` module. This module is configured by storing exportable symbols in the `@EXPORT_OK` global variable. So your code would become:

```
package Flame::Text;
use parent 'Exporter';  # inherit from Exporter
our @EXPORT_OK = qw/words/;  # list all subs which you want to export upon request

sub words { ... }
```

Now, `use Flame::Text 'words'` will work as expected.

Comment: Your post has been used to reproduce a bug. [See meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294342/1903366)

Answer (score 8):

You need to do something like this

```
package Flame::Text;
use Exporter 'import'; # gives you Exporter's import() method directly
@EXPORT_OK = qw(words);  # symbols to export on request
```

as perl doesn't export (or pollute) the namespace by default

http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html

don't forget to

```
use strict; use warnings;
```

in all things perl

Comment: Your post has been used to reproduce a bug. [See meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294342/1903366)